# Commence from or Commence to?

Tags: verbs, terminology

How is "Commence" correctly placed in a sentence as below?

1. The holiday will commence from Monday 2nd of May to Wednesday 4th of May
   (or)
2. The holiday will commence on Monday 2nd of May to Wednesday 4th of May

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, because the SE system can't recognise the question as answered if you do that (and neither can the OP accept such an answer). If you have an answer, write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong.

Commence means *to begin*. When you add *to*, you are talking about when it will end, and you can't keep using the verb *commence*. Some possible alternatives:

> The holiday will commence on Monday 2nd of May and conclude on Wednesday 4th of May.
> The holiday will commence on Monday 2nd of May and end on Wednesday 4th of May.
> The holiday will be celebrated from Monday 2nd of May to Wednesday 4th of May.

Answer (score 0):

*Commence* means *begin*, so you can't use it to refer to the duration of a holiday. Either the holiday begins **on** one date and ends on another, or it lasts/ extends **from** one date to another.

Answer (score 0):

As phrased, 'commence ' isn't really the right word to use at all, because on first reading it seems to say that the holiday will begin sometime between those two days. Some holidays or festival periods *are* uncertain in their timing.

I suggest these alternatives:

> The holiday will be on Monday 2nd of May to Wednesday 4th of May.
> The holiday will take place between Monday 2nd of May and Wednesday 4th of May.

If you want to use the word **commence** it could be phrased as

> The holiday will commence on Monday 2nd of May and last until Wednesday 4th of May.